# If $f(x)$ is increasing and non-negative, then is it true that $xf(x)$ is convex on $ [0,+\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

If $f(x)$ is increasing and non-negative, then is it true that $xf(x)$ is convex on $ [0,+\infty)$?

##########
Update:

If $f(x)$ is **second-order differentiabl, strictly increasing and non-negative on its domain**, then is it true that $xf(x)$ is convex on $ [0,+\infty)$?

Would there be a neat and intuitive counterexample?

@Lapin gave an constructed conterexample.

If we allow $f(x)$ to be non-decreasing, then the counterexample proposed by @KaviRamaMurthy is very neat:
$$ f(x)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0, x\le 0 \\
1-e^{-x^2}, x>0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Comment: $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ is a  counter-example.

Comment: $f(x)=x+\lfloor x\rfloor$ is also a counterexample

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Many thx to your counter-example! It is a good example if we only consider $f(x)$ on $[0, +\inf)$; however, is is not non-negative on its domain $R$.

Comment: You can just define it to be $0$ for $x <0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thx for your reminder!

Comment: $f(x)=1-e^{-x^{3}}$ for $x \geq 0$ and $0$ for $x <0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the edited question, $
g(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&x\le 0,\\
\exp(-x^{-2}),&x>0,
\end{cases}$, $h(x)=\dfrac\pi2+\arctan(x),
$ then$f(x)=g(x)+0.00001h(x)$
is still a counter-example. It is infinitely differentiable, strictly increasing and non-negative on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Indeed a counter-example! (need some efforts to verify this...